# Outlet component shifts my footer from visible page | React-router-dom with Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Please help me to solve my problem.
When I use

```
h-screen
```

to every element in Output, it makes scrolls on a single page which I don't need. My footer is not on the bottom of visible page, it's under Outler. How to make an Outlet not to shift my footer outside the visible page?

this is my main.jsx

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { createBrowserRouter, Outlet, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';
import Index from './pages/Index';
import './index.css';
import ErrorPage from './pages/ErrorPage';
import Personnel from './pages/Personnel';
import NewNavbar from './components/NewNavbar';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Contacts from './pages/Contacts';
import About from './pages/About';

const AppLayout = () => {
    return (
        <div className=' flex justify-between flex-col bg-gradient-to-r from-zinc-900 via-zinc-700 to-zinc-900'>
            <NewNavbar />
            <Outlet  />
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
};

const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        element: <AppLayout />,
        path: '/',
        errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
        children: [
            {
                index: true,
                element: <Index />,
            },
            {
                path: '/personnel',
                element: <Personnel />,
            },
            {
                path: '/contacts',
                element: <Contacts />,
            },
            {
                path: '/about',
                element: <About />,
            },
        ],
    },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Index, About and Contacts are similar

```
import React from 'react';

const Index = () => {
    return (
        <main className='bg-red-500 '>This is main page
        </main>
    );
};

export default Index;
```

As I said before Personnel.jsx works as I expected, but not sure that is right.

```
import React from 'react';
import Administration from '../components/Administration';
import Teachers from '../components/Teachers';

const Personnel = () => {
    return (
        
        <div className='flex w-full flex-col'>
            <div className='w-full px-[8%] lg:mx-auto lg:max-w-7xl text-white '>
                <Administration />
                <Teachers />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Personnel;
```

Each of these two elements has:

```
<div className='flex min-h-screen flex-col justify-center'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`h-screen` will set an element with `height: 100vh`, meaning it will take the span of the entire viewport.

If I understand your problem correctly, you should set your AppLayout component with `min-h-screen`, so all the components inside it (NewNavbar, Outlet and Footer) will take at least the height of the viewport:

```js
const AppLayout = () => {
    return (
        <div
            className='min-h-screen flex justify-between flex-col bg-gradient-to-r from-zinc-900 via-zinc-700 to-zinc-900'
        >
            <NewNavbar />
            <Outlet  />
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
};
```